# Regex Replace Expected Strings Or Byte Like Objects

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have [the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYg2T.png) , I have imported a dataset via Pandas, and am trying to substitute numbers with a comma out of it (for example, `"12,000"`) but I seem to always hit the error of `"TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"`

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/osc_samples_without.csv")
df2=df.loc[:,['Id','Description']]
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x:re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[,\.]','', df2))
```

Am a newbie with both Python and Regex, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please can you copy your code into the question? this makes things a lot easier to help you

Comment: Try `df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].str.replace(r'(?<=\d)[.,]', '')`

Comment: @wiktorStribizew Thanks !! It worked thanks to your input ! was wondering what seemed to be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `replace` directly without using `re` explicitly:

```
df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].str.replace(r'(?<=\d)[.,]', '')
```

Here,

- `(?<=\d)` -  a positive lookbehind that matches a position immediately preceded with a digit
- `[.,]` - matches a `.` or `,`.

Comment: Notably, the error encountered was due to passing the entire `df2` to `re.sub`